# cakephp upload plugin no input parameters can be change

Tags: php, cakephp

i just attached this plugin to my cakephp project:
https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload.

It took me a lot of time to realise that it is upload the files to the
webroot\files\model_name\filename folder, at first i thought no file was uploaded.
Database look like:

ID|descr|filename|filepath

I was try everything to modify input parameters,but nothing happened it is copy the file to the : webroot\files\model_name\filename over and over again.I tried to empty the cache but also does not worked.

```
 public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'path' => '{ROOT}{DS}webroot{DS}img{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',
        'filename'=> array(

    )
);
```

Also:

```
        public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'filename'=> array(
        'path' => '{ROOT}{DS}webroot{DS}img{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',        
            )
    )
);
```

Also:

```
     class User extends AppModel {
        public $actsAs = array(
            'Upload.Upload' => array(
                'filename' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'dir' => 'photo_dir'
                    )
                )
            )
        );

}
```

At this point i thought it doesn't works at all.So i modifed filename but than i got sql error,so it must work until this:

```
'Upload.Upload' => array(
'filename' => array(
```

I spent a lot of time to find solution(on sof,google everywhere).But not i dont know why i can not change the upload folder..

UPDATE1:
Made a small research:

```
class UploadBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

public $defaults = array(
    'rootDir' => null,
    'pathMethod' => 'primaryKey',
    'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}files{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',
..
```

However i can not modify the path parameter by my model,here i can change it and works well.

Comment: You should read the plugin's documentation. i think read the below article  [Basic example](http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#basic-example).

Answer (score 0):

For file uploading is sufficient raw php, just create a form with the attribute **enctype="multipart/form-data"** containing one or more **inputs of type file** and use a the simple php method **"move_uploaded_file"** to save it into the location you prefer.

Here is the example form:

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

And the php method:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 'yourpreferredpath/yourfile')
```

But in CakePhp, instead of $_FILES you must use $this->request->data, as this:

```
$this->request->data["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]
```

For more information look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: thank your answer.I was also able to implement the upload function without the plugin.I need the plugin because it has special function to handle thumbnails

Comment: what do they do these functions? Do you need crop functionality?

Comment: crop or resize these are necessarily for me that's why it is not enough the simple self writing code

Comment: If you need resize/crop functionality there is this plugin https://github.com/BradCrumb/CakeImageCropResize